# Intercept Text Messages : Debugging Problems

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using a simple BroadcastReceiver and onReceive method to intercept text messages as they come. For some reason, every time I send the text message: the app crashes. When I try to debug the app: I send the text message and the app still crashes but instead of taking me into the Receiver class, it suspends inside of the "ActivityThreadhandleReceiver(ActivityThread,ActivityThreadReceiverData)". The Debugging window just says for the Thread: "(Suspended(exception RuntimeException))".

How am I supposed to find out why my app is crashing if it won't allow me to step through my code.

Here is my Receiver Class:

```
public class FinderReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[ ] msgs = null;
String str = "";
if (bundle != null)
{
//---retrieve the received message here ---
Object[ ] pdus = (Object[ ]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[ ])pdus[i]);
str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
str += " :";
str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
str += "\n";
}
// ........first show sms here.....
Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".PhoneFinder_Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name=
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver> 
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Even after re-formatting the method to run inside of my main Activity I get the exact same result. This exact same method works upon the sending of texts Intent:

```
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    String RECEIVED = "SMS_RECEIVED";


    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    PendingIntent receivedPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(RECEIVED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FRIGGEN SMS!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(RECEIVED));
```

Comment: After attempting another way to go about this: I got the same error. So, I am assuming it's something to do with my manifest permissions or something of the sort. I edited the post above with both code snippets. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your manifest file -- the name of the receiver must be the name of the class.  So for your FinderReciever class above, you'd want:

```
<receiver android:name=".FinderReciever">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You can also verify that this is the problem by looking at logcat.  You should see something like:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1708): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver xxx.xxxx.SmsReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response! I resolved the issue by re-creating the project, doing which, I must have changed the name. Although I resolved the problem, I didn't know how. So thanks, I will make sure to keep this in mind for the future.